# Google Apps Script HTML - How to make a keyboard event trigger from an entire document rather than just a button?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, scope, keyboard-events

For Google Apps Script for Google Docs, in the Sidebar.html file I use this code(simplified to remove irrelevant parts):

```
<div class="sidebar branding-below">
  <form>
   <div class="block" id="button-bar">
      <button id="some-action" class="action">Action</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>

  $(function() {
    $('#some-action').click(doSomething);           //call the method below on button click
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(loadPreferences)
        .withFailureHandler(showError).getPreferences();  //not sure what this does
  });

  $(document).keydown(function(e){             //only applies to button??
    //output whatever key was pressed under the button
    var div = $('<div id="clickmsg" class="text">' + 'KeyPressed: ' + e.which + '</div>');
    $('#button-bar').after(div);
    //Detect CTRL + q keydown combo, which should be unused in windows and chrome
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 81){
      var div = $('<div id="clickmsg" class="text">' + 'Ctrl+Q detected' + '</div>');
      $('#button-bar').after(div);
      doSomething();                           //calls the method below
    }
  });

  function doSomething() {
    this.disabled = true;
    $('#error').remove();
    google.script.run
        [some code...] //doStuff
  }
</script>
```

The doSomething() only triggers when I have tabbed to the button. Thus, as long as the button is still under tabbed selection, then the keys that I am pressing are displayed below it. However, under any circumstance where I have not tabbed to the button, no matter what keys are pressed, this key press code does not output anything.

Note that I use $(document).keydown, but never defined "document" anywhere. However, somehow it automatically binds to the button in the sidebar. Why does this happen, instead of returning an error? How do I make it detect keyboard shortcuts in all of the google doc, even if the user is just typing? Is HTML even the right way to detect this?

I know this is (probably) possible because of this post about an issue that I used the keybind code from, the [issue here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=306#c33), where the person who posted toe code said that "the new IFRAME mode in HtmlService does allow for key codes to be passed on to Add-ons", as long as the user has "click[ed] on / activate[d] the sidebar first."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML gets wrapped by the HTML service, like this:

```
<iframe>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <more boilerplate...>
    ...

      your html

     ...
</iframe>
```

So, `document` is defined, and has a scope limited to the `iframe`. Since you only have one element within your form, focus must be there for the `document` to receive events.

If your intent is to capture all keystrokes in the Google Doc, you will not be able to do that within a Google Apps Script. A browser extension may be able to, though.